# Applying polynomial time approximation scheme (PTAS) on an algorithm

Tags: polynomials, computer-science, approximation

I am trying to understand how we can apply PTAS on an algorithm. I think that we apply PTAS on the running time equation of the algorithm. We use the term (1-ϵ) and (1+ ϵ) in the running time of the algorithm but I don’t know how we insert these terms in the running time equation of the algorithm, and that’s what I want to understand. Also how we evaluate the value of ϵ.

Let's suppose we have a algorithm:

M = K * Y

Let’s the running time of algorithm is pseudo-polynomial i.e

p(n) * K

where k and p(n)  are polynomial in n.
Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand what PTAS means.  You don't "apply it on an algorithm", and you don't "insert" any terms in its running time.  You have a minimization problem for which there may or may not be an efficient algorithm.  But what you do have is
an algorithm that, given any instance $x$ of the problem and a rational number $r > 1$, produces a solution whose objective value is at most $r$ times the optimal value.
For any given $r$ the running time of this algorithm is polynomial in the size of $x$ (but the dependence on $r$ is arbitrary, so it may be extremely hard to get very good approximations).  That is a Polynomial-Time Approximation Scheme or PTAS for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I thought insertion because after PTAS running time has a term ϵ as for Knapsack, running time = O(NW) and PTAS = O(f(ϵ)n g(ϵ) ) https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~cs224/spring17/lec/lec13.pdf. Do you mean 'r' same as  ϵ? Do we have to find some ratio for PTAS? What can be the ratio in my example?